# Hapi.js create dynamic path based on current url

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm really new to Node.js. Currently I'm using Hapi.js.
Based on Hapi.js documentation, the sample provided is to hardcoded the path to a handler.
Is it possible to map dynamically generated path to a handler?
For example: I have a server route that receives * path, based on the path value, I will go find that particular item in the file and reply it back to user.
The reason of me doing this is that, if I hardcoded the path with handler, every time I have changed the file name, I need to manually update the path. This will be very troublesome.

Comment: So, you want a static file server?

Comment: @JoshC. thx, let me check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [File handler](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/serving-files#file-handler) and [Directory handler](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/serving-files#directory-handler) sections in the tutorial. A sample code for a directory handler:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{param*}',
    handler: {
        directory: {
            path: 'public'
        }
    }
});
```